# How to implement Path's timeline style tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timeline

I'm trying to implement a timeline liked path in my iPhone app. I think tableview should be used here. But in Path, each table cell will be different if the content is different. For example when there is a location available, there be a location icon in the timeline. Like the following:

[image]

I think the cell in tableview should be similar, so I'm confused how to implement a timeline like Path. Is there any good idea or reference or open source I can learn from? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a great book on iOS Table Views. It even discusses things pertaining to how Path did their UITableView layouts with custom view cells. I'm about half-way through it and have learned a lot.

[Pro iOS Table Views: for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007JYSZW0)

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following sample , it will give you an idea about the implementation of path like tableview,

https://github.com/fumin65/path

see the following path demo project

https://github.com/JPluto/Path2DemoPrj

Comment: Seems not what I want. There is just a picture works like path, no tableview or any cell.

Comment: you can't find better than this sample... appart from that you have to work for your exact requirement...